# I want some slide out effect on button

Tags: html, css, animation

I have four button based on that whenever i click on some button it should slide out the background color to the particular button

```css
.active{
color:white;
background-color:blue;

}
button{
background-color:dodgerblue;
color:white;
box-shadow:none;
border:1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button  class="active">Avon</utton>
  <button>Biseri</button>
  <button>Poliadal</button>
  <button>Aqualitical</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `-webkit-transition`

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  if (document.querySelector('#navList a.active') !== null) {
    document.querySelector('#navList a.active').classList.remove('active');
  }
  e.target.className = "active";
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: pink;
  background-color: beige;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -3.25em 0 0 beige;
}

button {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #D80286;
  -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  transition: ease-out 0.4s;
  padding: 18px 36px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <button>Avon</button>
    <button>Biseri</button>
    <button>Poliadal</button>
    <button>Aqualitical</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't need vendor prefixes for transitions. Doubt you need that old support.

Comment: no not o hover i want to have effect on based of active stage like for examle right now avon is active when bisleri will be active the color should be move from avon to bisleri if bisleri is clicked

Comment: current u have property on hover i want it on click , secondly the background color should translate from the active button to the next active button which is about to beclicked

Comment: no this is not what i want https://codepen.io/giana/pen/BZaGyP in this i want it something like slide . and it should come back like from the previous active button

Comment: https://codepen.io/personable/pen/stpwD if u see this code the switch is moving from active state to next active state  want the same with my button. what you are doing is not even close of waht i want. Also on click of next button the aactive state from previous state should be removed

Answer (score 0):

Given the css for just first button changing it from yellow to red.

```js
 function changecolor(){
    document.getElementById('color').className ='classname';
  }
```

```css
.active{
color:pink;
background-color:beige;

}
button{
background-color:aqua;
color:white;
box-shadow:none;
border:1px solid transparent;
}
.classname {
  -webkit-animation-name: cssAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
   background: yellow;
  }
  to {
  background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
 <button  class="active" onclick="changecolor()" id="color">Avon</utton>
  <button>Biseri</button>
  <button>Poliadal</button>
  <button>Aqualitical</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you new style ;

https://jsfiddle.net/uniak/ksL21o9y/

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  font-family: arial;
  display:flex;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}


.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
}

.btn > a {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: dodgerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  text-decoration:none
}

/* sliders */
.btn:before{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

/* Left Slider */
.btn-z:before{
  top: 0;
  left: -210px;
}


.btn-z:hover:before{
  left: 0;
}

.btn:hover a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <div class="btn btn-z">
    <a href="#"><p>Come On ME!</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-z">
    <a href="#"><p>Come On BABY!</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-z">
    <a href="#"><p>Come On LETS GO!</p></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-z">
   <a href="#"><p>Come On WTF!</p></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: can we have this effect on click only not on hover